# Set session lifetime with createUserSession()

Tags: wakanda

Is there a way to set the session lifeTime for sessions created with the `createUserSession()` methode?

i can only find the option with `loginByPassword()` or `loginByKey()` which is not possible in this case ([http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda Studio/0.Beta/lifeTime.303-1005364.en.html](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda%20Studio/0.Beta/lifeTime.303-1005364.en.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to set the session life time. However, it will be available in next v1.1.0 release.

```
createUserSession({
    ID: "0001000100010001000100010001000100010001",
    name: "jsmith",
    lifeTime: 60*60, //seconds
    fullName: "Jennifer Smith"
});
```

Hope it helps